# How to invoke async method in C# by using reflection and won't cause deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to invoke a async method by a `Task<T>` type reflection instance,I had used `Task.WaitAll` and `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`,but all they will cause deadlock.
How should I do now?

For example:

Given

```
async Task<T> Add<T>(T model);
```

This is how I do it

```
void InvokeByReflection(object model) { 
    MethodInfo method = typeof(SAMPLE).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod("Add"); 
}
```

How to invoke method without deadlock?

Comment: Can you post a code example? What is the type of your application? console? win forms? asp.net?

Comment: For the question of how to use reflection to invoke a method, whether it causes deadlock is irrelevant. For the question of how to wait for a task without causing deadlock, whether you use reflection is irrelevant. They're two unrelated questions. Which of the two do you need help with?

Comment: * For example: 

`
async Task<T> Add<T>(T model);

void InvokeByReflection(object model)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(SAMPLE).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod("Add");
   //How to invoke method without deadlock?
}
`

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear how reflection has anything to do with deadlock.
Calling async methods is fairly simple:

Critical - need async here:

```
async void InvokeByReflection(SAMPLE sample, object model) { 
   await (Task)typeof(SAMPLE)
       .GetTypeInfo()
       .GetMethod("Add")
       .MakeGenericMethod(new []{model.GetType()})
       .Invoke(sample, new object[]{ model }); 
}
```

Optionally, if you're in the web using full .Net Framework, don't forget `.ConfigureAwait(false);` (this is no longer critical for .Net Core because Kestrel dispatches all requests on the threadpool, not main thread).

*UPDATE* to get results out:

```
    async void InvokeByReflectionAndgetResult(SAMPLE sample, object model) { 
     var task =(Task)typeof(SAMPLE)
     .GetTypeInfo()
     .GetMethod("Add")
     .MakeGenericMethod(new []{model.GetType()})
     .Invoke(sample, new object[]{ model }); 
     await task;
     var result = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
    }
```

Comment: I want to just cast T as object , instead of including 'T' in method signature,

Comment: Sure, see my edit.

Comment: How can I get the result of Add<T>?

Comment: see another edit :) Next time please include all requirements in the original question, it helps to answer them in full

Comment: You should avoid `async void` - use `async Task` or `async Task<dynamic>` instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary that really depends on the workflow you are using.

Comment: Wonder why i got the downvote.